# Sending a variable with ajax call .done

Tags: javascript, ajax, call

Is there a possible way to send the variable, 'schedule_id[i]', with the result of the call. Also is it possible to add this variable in the data object?

My code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < schedule_id.length; i++) {

    //Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.viewer.zmags.com/schedules/" + schedule_id[i] + "?key=" + api_key
    })

    //
    .done(function(data){

}
```

Comment: Doing ajax calls in a loop is bad practice.   Source all your needed schedules in one call, and then loop through the result set locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need asynchronies ajax call in synchronies manner right?

So you need to create one separate function which is call ajax request and return the result and use in subsequent request.

**Like:-**

```
for (var i = 0; i < schedule_id.length; i++) {
    var result;
    if (i == 0)
        result = callfunction(0,schedule_id[i]);
    else
        result = callfunction(result,schedule_id[i]);
}

function callfunction(passresult,schedule_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.viewer.zmags.com/schedules/" + schedule_id + "?key=" + api_key
    })
  .done(function (data) {
      return data;
  });
}
```

Comment: The schedule[i] can't be known because you close the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

construct the ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.viewer.zmags.com/schedules/',
    type: 'POST' // or GET,
    data: {
        schedule_ids: schedule_id, //array
        key: api_key
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //success callback
    }
});
```